# <input type='date'> crashes Dartium on selection of a date

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Any attempt select a date crashes Dartium.

Given the simple .html markup below, the calendar renders as expected, but selection of any date crashes Dartium browser

```
<div>
  <input required
         id='birthday'
         type='date'>
</div>
```

I reported this earlier and it was fixed, but it has now returned. I am using WebStorm on Windows 8 x64 with the latest dart-sdk (x64) and dartium (x32) (DEV for both).

It seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue in Dartium. See http://dartbug.com/23416.

Comment: But this has been going on for an inordinately long time. There have been several DEV builds since. Could someone say why such a seemingly basic problem cannot be fixed?

Comment: No idea unfortunately.